# Avoid Formatting of cells in excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I m getting table from server and i want put in excel table.

I m using javascript to put table in excel.

if my table column value is "Jan-09" then it formats into "09-Jan". So we get The Problem when we comparing the column names.

I want to avoid that formatting if my table column name is "Jan-09" then also in excel table i want "Jan-09".

Is there any way that avoid formatting when we put the table data values in excel???

Comment: what code are you using to convert to excel...??

Comment: it is so lengthy. when i putting the values in excel then it should avoid formatting

Comment: Without the code that is causing problem, you are unlikely to get an answer and your question may be closed as off topic.  In general, if the Excel cell to which you are writing is formatted as Text **before** the writing of the data, or if the data being written is declared as Text (in Excel one might precede the data with a single quote `'`), then Excel will not do its *Date Magic*

Comment: Thanks It worked i put n the code " ' " preceding data